# Error creating bean with name 'application', No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I don't quite understand why this code gives me 'no default constructor found' error. The constructor is @Autowired. Everything seems to be injected correctly. Can anybody please help? Thanks

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private MessagingService messagingService;
    private Parser parser;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    public Application(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                       MessagingService messagingService,
                       Parser parser)
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        Assert.notNull(messagingService, "MessagingService must not be null");
        this.messagingService = messagingService;
        Assert.notNull(parser, "Parser must not be null");
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner app() {
        return args -> {
            Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
            log.info("Using MessagingService: " + messagingService.getMyMessageCode());

            parser.parse();
        };
    }
}
```

**Edit:** updated *Application.class*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private MessagingService messagingService;
    @Autowired
    private Parser parser;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public Application() {}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner app() {
        return args -> {
            Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
            log.info("Using MessagingService: " + messagingService.getMyMessageCode());

            parser.parse();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: default constructor means constructor without any argument. Look at your code if you have any default constructor. Don't use other spring annotation in your main class with @SpringBootAnnotation annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't autowire into main Spring Boot class. You can inject dependencies needed for `CommandLineRunner` as parameters of method annotated with `@Bean` and of course remove constructor injection for main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner app(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                       MessagingService messagingService,
                       Parser parser) {
        return args -> {
            Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
            log.info("Using MessagingService: " + messagingService.getMyMessageCode());

            parser.parse();
        };
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Correct context configuration after edit:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public Application() {}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner app(MessagingService messagingService, Parser parser) {
        return args -> {
            Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale);
            log.info("Using MessagingService: " + messagingService.getMyMessageCode());

            parser.parse();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know. I have made an edit to my class, can you please take a look and tell me if I can inject my dependencies in such manner also as it seems to be more clean in my opinion?

Comment: I included correct context configuration for your class updated class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it is OK to inject as many dependencies into my CommandLineRunner app as I need. The reason I am asking is that I had done this before and have been told, that is it not correct and should be done as per my EDIT version of the class.

Comment: Injection via `@Bean` method parameters is perfectly valid and supported feature of Spring IoC container. If anybody says "it is not correct", he should educate himself.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from [luboskrnac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39434459/5065092) is correct.

But if you really want to use **`Constructor Injection`** you can **upgrade** you **`SpringBoot`** version to **`1.4.0.RELEASE`** which will use **`Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE`**

From **Spring 4.3** **Constructor Injection** is supported on **`@Configuration`** class

[New Features and Enhancements in Spring Framework 4.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.3.html)

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why constructor injection was working almost everywhere at work, but not at home. I have version 1.4.0 of spring boot at work, but 1.2.3 at home. Thanks for the tip!